# Ident authentication failed on PostgreSQL through SSH tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have PostgreSQL server and a seperate computer is a client of it. They are in one network. If I use  psql command like

`psql --host db_ip_address --port 5432 --user user base_name`

connection goes fine and all works.

But if I'll open SSH tunnel to DB server like:

`ssh -L 63333:localhost:5432 root@db_ip_address`

and then try to do the same like:

`psql --host localhost --port 63333 --user user base_name`

than it suddenly output error message:

`psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "user"`

pg_hba.conf on server have this lines:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.49/32         trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.50/32         trust
host    all             all             192.168.0.48/32         trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I need to use SSH tunnels because I actually need one more tunnel for my own computer, and it is the only way to get connection for db on it.
And I don't want to change any configuration or base on PostgreSQL server, because it is working in real time server.
Hope for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the error message and `pg_hba.conf`, the server resolves `localhost` to its IPv6 address, which is tied to `ident` authentication.

As a solution, you may either:

- change `pg_hba.conf` to set `trust` method for `::1/128`, as is already the case for `127.0.0.1/32`
- or run `psql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 63333 [other options]...` to force the IPv4 address.

Comment: Actually, that's looks like a solution. I just make tunnels using 
```ssh -L 63333:127.0.0.1:5432 root@db_ip_address``` and that suddenly works! Thanx!

Comment: i'm running into this issue, where I need to portforward in order for it to connect, otherwise it gives me an invalid password error (which is a red herring cause the password is correct).  Do we know what is causing this?  I'm using auroa aws, so I don't have access to the hba.conf file, I do however has parameter groups, where I can made config changes.  which property is it in the hba.conf?